# PHP Zip extractTo - problem with permissions

Tags: php, permissions, zip, zlib

I'm trying to unzip a Zip archive in PHP using `extractTo`.  The PHP script is running via the web browser i.e. as "nobody".

The logic and flow:

1. creates a new subdirectory (e.g. "abc"), with permissions 0777 and owner "nobody" under document root (i.e. one level above public_html)
2. copies the Zip file (from an incoming FTP directory under public_html) to the abc subdirectory.  Permissions on this Zip file are set to 0777, owner "nobody".
3. creates an "unzipped" subdirectory under abc, permissions 0777 / nobody
4. calls `extractTo` to unzip the zip file to the unzipped subdirectory.

The code is:

```
if ($zip->extractTo('$abc_unzipped_path') === TRUE)
{
     [more code]
}
```

Step 4 results in the php script returning the following error:

> ZipArchive::extractTo() [ziparchive.extractto]: Permission denied in [script path and name] on line [line number of extractTo call]

Can anyone see where the problem with the permissions might be please?

- PHP version 5.2.9
- Zlib 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

... turns out the problem was with the zip file itself, which variously caused the above errors, or no error message at all (script crash)